# Objectify v5 and v6 at the same time in a google app engine java 8 standard project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We want to do a zero downtime migration of a google app engine java 8 standard project to another region.
Unfortunately google does not support this, so it has to be done manually.
One could export the datastore and import it again, but **there may be no downtime** and the data must always be consistent.

So the idea came up to create the project in the new region, and embed objectify 5 there with all entities (definitions, not data) used in the old project. Any new data goes in the "new datastore" attached to this new project.

All data not found on this new datastore shall be queried (if necessary) using objectify 6 connected to the "old" project using datastore api.

The advantage would be to not export any data manually at all and only migrate the most important data on the fly, using the mechanism above. (there's a lot of unused garbage, we did not do housekeeping for, but also some very vital data that must be on the new system)

Is this a valid approach? I know I'll probably integrate objectify by code and change package names to not have problems on the "code side"

If there is a better approach to migrate a project to another region, we're happy to hear.
We searched for hours without a proper result

[image: Simple image to visualize the process]

Edit: I'm aware that we must instantly stop requests to the old service / disable writes there. We'd solve this by redirecting traffic (http) from the old project to the new one and disable writes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid approach for migration. The traffic from new project can continue to do reads from old Datastore and writes to new one. I would like to add one more point.

However, soon after this switchover you should also plan data migration from old datastore to new one through mass export and import. The app will then have to be pointed to the new ones even for reads. https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities

This can be done gracefully by introducing a proxy connection logic in JAVA for connecting with the new Datastore entity. Which means during data migration, you put a condition in OFY6 to check for the new Datastore entity, if it is not available then read data from the old entity. This will ensure Zero downtime and in the backend you can silently and safely turn off the old datastore assuming you already have its full export.

Answer (score 0):

Reads from both the old data source and new data source is a valid way to do migrations.